# Trying to run meteor up mup setup

Tags: meteor

It appears mup setup can't run without a mup.json file. But, it appears the mup.json file is primarily used for mup deploy. Reason I ask is I'm trying to execute mup setup on the host server and it fails without the server credentials but considering that I'm already logged onto the server executing the setup I don't understand why the mup.json is being required in the first place?  I'm not deploying an application so none of the application-specific settings would apply, right?  If I don't have a mup.json on the server then mup setup throws an error that the mup.json file does not exist.  It didn't seem really clear on the meteor up web site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run Meteor Up from your local machine as that's what it's designed for. I wrote about how to deploy with [meteor up](http://johngibby.com/blog/How_to_deploy_your_meteor.js_app_on_Digital_Ocean) a while back and that should help you.

In a nutshell I believe you're thinking about this the wrong way. With mup, meteor deploy and soon galaxy deploy, you no longer need to "upload" your files and then go and manage them from the server. Instead your files stay local, you deploy (which will upload them) and deployment sets up your server and file structure.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was looking at it from the wrong direction

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstanding on my part. mup setup is something you run on your remote machine, not the host machine.